# Clarify the purpose of SE in the app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

The SE app has been around for a while now and it helps a lot.
But some people (mostly new users) ask questions and are told their questions are off topic.

I think that the "about" section of the app should talk about what the app is supposed to be used for.
At least when this is included in the "about" section, it will be clear enough for new users to understand the use of SE.

I mean like this..[image]

Comment: So something in addition to the about http://superuser.com/tour

Comment: Where is the "about" section that you are talking about?  Is it perhaps a [Tour] or a [Help] or something else?

Comment: what app? you mean a different Stack Exchange Site? as already pointed out by the comments above each the tour has the *"Don't ask about..."* section in it and the help center's [Asking page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which is different between [different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [sites](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). also some sites deploy the use of notifications on the right when asking question or when you use a certain tag

Comment: Now that's a great piece of something random... So can it be made available to the newbie as they install the app? Cos most people have found these rules out the hard way.

Comment: I've edited your question; I believe it should now be more clear. If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back. To roll back, click on the "edited ... ago" link above my user icon. That takes you to the edit history, where the rollback options are.

Answer (score 2):

So you want more explanation for new users in the "About" field in the app.

I think that's actually a good idea, although as the comments have indicated it needs some fleshing out.

The "About" box gives a lot of info, including a link to the Terms & Services. A link to a Help Center could easily fit in there.

The hard part is that different sites have different rules. For example, recommendations are off-topic on most sites, but on-topic on Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations (within the rules for those sites).

If we could find some general rules, we could have a page for that, and link it in the About box. Above or below the link to Terms & Services seems a good place.
This page could explain that different SE sites have their own rules, and link to the Help Centers of the different SE sites.

So yes, it's a lot of work. It's not as simple as adding a link, it requires some good thinking about what text should be in there.
But if that helps new users understand our model better, that's a win for all.